# Does the WHERE IN clause return results in the order of the array passed in?

Tags: mysql

If I were to run a sample query along the lines of:

```
SELECT songIDs FROM blah WHERE fileID IN($fileIDs)
```

Would MySQL always return songIDs in the order $fileIDs was passed in? I need to be able to have them matched up index for index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A SELECT statement is not guaranteed to return rows in any specific order, absent an `ORDER BY` clause on the query.

(The one exception with MySQL is that a `GROUP BY` implies an `ORDER BY` on the same list of  expressions in the `GROUP BY` clause.)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is **NO**.

The result will be return in any order the databaser engine sees fit, unless you specify an [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)